# Why is it true that every set can be classified as ordinary or extraordinary(not ordinary)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The statements of Russell's Paradox are presented below (in more or less elaborate form):

1. A set is called ordinary if it does not contain itself as an element.
2. A set is called extraordinary if it contains itself as an element.
3. Consider the set of all ordinary sets ***C***.
4. ***C*** **is either ordinary or extraordinary**.
5. If ***C*** is ordinary then by definition of ***C*** (st.3) it should contain itself and therefore should be extraordinary. This contradicts the assumption and hence, ***C*** should be extraordinary.
6. But, if ***C*** is extraordinary, then it contains itself. This contradicts the very definition of ***C*** whereby it was to contain ordinary sets only. Therefore ***C*** cannot be extraordinary.

Thus, the paradox.

But.....

The problem is with the statement **4** above. It says ***C*** is either ordinary or not ordinary. This probably follows from the seemingly obvious statement:

> Every set is either of one type or *not*.

But, even though it seems obvious, what is the proof that it is true? In fact, there seems to be a counter-example, namely, ***THE VERY SET: *C*. *** 
As statements **5** and **6** together imply, it is impossible to classify ***C*** as either ordinary or not ordinary (i.e.,extraordinary).

Shouldn't a hypothesis (here, the statement in >blockquote< ), however obvious or axiomatic it looks, be discarded as soon as a counter-example is found?

Comment: Unwind the def: "a set $C$ is either ordinary or extraordinary" is: "Either $C$ contains itself as an element or $C$ does **not** contain itself as an element." It is an "application" of Exclude Middle.

Comment: But we can debate about the "universal validity" of Excluded Middle; see [Intuitionism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/).

Comment: [Russell's Paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/) presupposes some principles: the *Comprehension Principle*: "the axiom that for any formula $\varphi(x)$ containing $x$ as a free variable, there will exist the set $\{ x : \varphi(x) \}$ whose members are exactly those objects that satisfy $\varphi(x)$."

Comment: As well as the principle "that any well-defined condition (or precisely specified property) could be used to determine a set." And this one embodies Exckude Middle.

Comment: Well, then isn't Russell's "paradox" a counter-example of the fact that anything well-defined is always either of one type or the other (Excluded middle) ? If you are of the opinion that the set C is not well-defined, what are your reasons?

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA. Also, is it that it is easier to discard set C as "not well-defined" than to discard the very obvious principle of the Excluded Middle?

Comment: The "decision" we take was (see Russell and hisory of set theory) to discard the universal validity of *Comprehension principle*.

Comment: It boils down the logical tautology $\neg \exists C: \forall x: [x\in C \iff x\notin x]$ which contradicts a theorem of an early attempt to axiomatize to set theory by G. Frege. That is the real paradox.

Comment: "Shouldn't a hypothesis (here, the statement in >blockquote< ), however obvious or axiomatic it looks, be discarded as soon as a counter-example is found?" What about the hypothesis "$C$ exists"? You seem to treat that statement (and full comprehension in general) as beyond reproach, and view the laws of classical logic (although per Max' answer, much less is necessary here) as subject to inquiry. I don't understand how you view the former as more fundamental than the latter - can you clarify your position?

Comment: @DanChristensen I don't really think that's what they're asking: they're aware of the contradiction in classical logic, they're asking why we don't view this as an indictment of classical logic.

Comment: @NoahSchweber If you assume $\exists c: \forall x: [x R c \iff \neg x R x]$ is true, then you get the obvious contradiction. So, the original assumption would have to be false -- proof by contradiction. It doesn't matter what domain or relation you are talking about.

Comment: @NoahSchweber The paradox only arises in Frege's set theory because his axiom of unrestricted comprehension says that the set $C$ does exist.

Comment: @DanChristensen Yes, I am of course aware of this. But the point of this whole question is why the laws of logic that *yield* that contradiction are considered more fundamental than full comprehension, not *why* full comprehension is inconsistent *with classical logic*. (I promise you, I understand quite well why full comprehension is inconsistent.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber The following little exercise convinced me years ago that the problem with RP was not in the rules of logic. Consider a relation $R$ on a set $S=\{ 0, 1\}$ There are only 16 possibilities. It is easy to verify that in each case, there will not exist an $x\in S$ such that for all $y\in S, yRx\iff \neg yRy$.

Comment: @DanChristensen That assumes Boolean truth values - that the relation either holds or doesn't hold on a given element/tuple! Laws of logic **are** necessary to prove **anything**, that's how proofs work. Now you may argue that the laws of classical logic are "self-evident," and I'd agree - but the fact is that some laws are needed to derive explosion from full comprehension, and the OP is asking about the relative "self-evident-ness" of those laws versus full comprehension.

Comment: @NoahSchweber It seems obvious to me that you should be able to derive $\neg \exists c: \forall x: [xRc \iff \neg xRx]$ in FOL.

Comment: @DanChristensen Yes, **but FOL uses classical logic**! And the priority given to the laws of classical logic *over* full comprehension **is exactly what the OP is asking about**. As my last comment, let me observe that naive (that is, with full comprehension) set theory *has* been studied in contexts (like relevant logic) where it does not "explode" - we **can indeed** save full comprehension if we weaken our logic sufficiently. Plenty of such sources can be found by googling "paraconsistent set theory."

Comment: @NoahSchweber Sounds like trying to do mathematics with one arm tied behind your back and quite pointless. Anyway, we do seem to be going in circles here. Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: @DanChristensen I would agree, but that's what the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 4):

The reason people reject the definition of $C$ rather than the law of excluded middle (LEM- it has been mentioned in the comments) is because the latter seems way more intuitive: either somehting is true, or it is false; whereas the existence of $C$ relies on being able to define a "set of all objects that have property $\phi$", which is much less obvious.

However, a better reason to discard the existence of $C$ rather than the LEM, is the following: suppose for every property $\phi$, there is a set of all things that satisfy $\phi$.  Now let $P$ be any formula/property you like ($0=1$, "I am wonderwoman", "I can fly", really anything you like.). Consider $C = \{ x : x\in x \to P\}$. Then $C\in C \implies (C\in C \implies P)$ is true. However $(A\implies (A\implies B)) \implies (A\implies B)$ is an intuitionistic tautology, which means it doesn't rely on the LEM ! You can try to prove it by yourself and you'll see that nothing more than the definition of $\implies$ and modus ponens is necessary.

Therefore this implies $C\in C \implies P$, which by definition of $C$ implies $C\in C$, which together with $C\in C \implies P$, implies $P$.

Therefore $P$ is true, and I haven't used the LEM: accepting the existence of such $C$'s allows me to prove anything: that's why we discard it; so actually the paradox in question doesn't even need the LEM

Comment: +1. It's worth noting that there are even weaker logics than intuitionistic logic - e.g. [relevance logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_logic) - which (if I recall correctly) can soften this blow. However, such logics are really extremely weak, and frankly I'm always surprised by claims that set comprehension is more fundamental than the basic laws of logic. (This isn't to say that there aren't serious arguments for e.g. intuitionism, although personally I'm not swayed by them; rather, that the goal of making full comprehension consistent seems a *terrible* argument to me.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I was also surprised to see someone questioning the LEM before the full comprehension axiom; usually it doesn't even come to the mind of people to think that one may want to deny it, because it's so strongly associated with the principle of non contradiction.

Comment: IIUC you have proven that unrestricted comprehension leads to all propositions $P$ being true. Even propositions that contradict one another, e.g. $P$ and $\neg P.$ So all propositions would be both true and false. This is obviously undesirable, but the intuitionists stop short of calling this a "contradiction." Correct?

Comment: It's correct until your last sentence that I don't really understand : proving $P\land \neg P$ is an intuitionistic contradiction (even a linear contradiction if I'm not mistaken). What kind of logical system wouldn't treat it as a contradiction ?

Comment: It would certainly be a weird system. But thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very odd presentation of Russell's Paradox. The introduction of the notions of "ordinary" and "extraordinary" sets actually leads to some confusion. Your statement 4 is simply not required as an explicit assumption to be discharged.

Using a variant of FOL, you would usually prove by contradiction that $\neg \exists a: \forall b: [b\in a \iff b\notin b]$ as follows:

1. $\exists a: \forall b: [b\in a \iff b\notin b]\space \space$ (Premise)
2. $\forall b: [b\in C \iff b\notin b]\space \space$ (Existential Specification, 1)
3. $C\in C \iff C\notin C\space \space$ (Universal Specfication, 2)
4. $\neg \exists a: \forall b: [b\in a \iff b\notin b] \space \space$ (Conclusion, 1, 3)

By no means then is rejecting the Law of the Excluded Middle (LEM) required to resolve Russell's Paradox (RP).

Comment: I think for the purposes of this question, you should do the whole derivation. In particular, I don't know of any (maybe you do, in that case I'd be glad to learn about it !) proof system where $P\iff \neg P$ is automatically a contradiction (i.e. there's usually no rule that goes from such a sentence to $\bot$)

Comment: $(P \land \neg P) \iff (P \iff \neg P)$ is a tautology. See truth table at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth+table+(p+%26+~p)%3C%3D%3E+(p+%3C%3D%3E+~p)

Comment: Ok but using truth tables is essentially using LEM

Comment: @Max In his informal proof, the OP needlessly introduces line 4: "C is either ordinary or extraordinary" as an assumption (premise) that supposedly needs to discharged (reading between the lines). It seems to me that this is only reason that LEM comes up.

Comment: What I mean is that if you allow truth tables, then you allow classical tautologies, of which there are more than intuitionistic tautologies. In particular, the OP could say "3. $C\in C \lor C\notin C$" (Tautology, see the truth tables).

Comment: @Max What I mean is that rejecting LEM is by no means required to resolve RP as seems to be suggested by the OP.

Comment: Yes, and what I mean is that your proof uses LEM, so although you show that it is not required, you don't show why it wasn't done

Comment: @Max Was that a typo? I  showed that REJECTING LEM is not required.Nothing new or radical here. Just a textbook exercise in FOL.

Comment: I'm sorry I may not be clear enough: you show that rejecting the LEM is *not* required, but you don't explain why it wasn't done; why logicians at the beginning of the 20th century didn't say "Oh well, to hell with the LEM" : what you show is that one has a choice of either rejecting the LEM or, as your argument proves, simply the existence of the set in question; but why did mathematicians choose the latter ? (that being said, it doesn't explain the downvote on your post, and I don't understand why you have been downvoted)

Comment: @Max Given a choice between LEM and the existence of the Russel Set, it seems obvious to me. While it may be interesting and fun to see how far you can get in mathematics without implicitly citing LEM, to most mathematicians, it must seem like working with one arm tied behind one's back -- a completely artificial, self-imposed restriction. As for the downvote, I'm pretty sure what is going on here. And that it probably has nothing to do with my actual posting.

Comment: It seems obvious to me too, but apparently not to the OP, that was the point of my comments. But the thing is, there is a problem even without the LEM (that's what I show in my answer); so the answer really is to let go of the Russell set

Comment: @Max But how do you "let go of the Russell Set" without LEM using only a subset of FOL?

Comment: Well as I show in my answer, intuitionistic logic is enough to prove the theorem you prove at the end !